# Ajuda consulta SQL SERVER com 3 tabelas distintas

Tags: c#, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, query

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta no banco de dados fazendo um `select` com `join` em 3 tabelas que me tragam o resultado da 1 tabela completo, 2 tabela somente 1 coluna e 3 tabela somente 1 coluna, porém o que tem na 2 e 3 tabela a coluna tem que ser unida, eu consegui fazer o `select` com `join` só que a coluna da 2 e 3 tabela não se uniram e criou 2 colunas diferentes, fiz assim o meu `select`

```
SELECT DISTINCT
T.id, T.chave, T.natop, T.CFOP, T.nome, T.n_NF, T.data_emissao_NF, T.total_NF, T.endereco, T.cidade, T.bairro, T.uf, T.cep, T.pais, T.cnpj, T.nome_transp, T.cnpj_transp, T.qtd_vol_transp, T.peso_l_transp, T.peso_b_transp, T.total_BC,
T.total_icms, T.total_prod, T.total_frete, T.total_ipi, T.total_pis, T.total_cofins, T.total_trib, T.tipo_emissao, T.tipo_frete, T.tipo_pgto, T2.N_Conta_Contabil AS CONTABIL, T3.Nome_Conta_Contabil AS CONTABIL
FROM NF_Completa AS T LEFT OUTER JOIN
Tabela_CP AS T2 ON T.chave = T2.Chave_Acesso FULL OUTER JOIN
LANÇAMENTO AS T3 ON T.chave = T3.Chave_Acesso
```

RESULTADO:

[image: RESULTADO]

queria unir as 2 ultimas colunas na consulta onde na coluna `CONTABIL` esta NULL, unir o valor da coluna `CONTABIL_FT`

Comment: Fiquei com dúvida do que você quer fazer, mas verifique as funções Coalesce e Concat, acho que com elas você consegue obter o resultado esperado

Answer (score -1):

```sql
select 
  T.id,
  T.chave,
  T.natop,
  T.CFOP,
  T.nome,
  T.n_NF,
  T.data_emissao_NF,
  T.total_NF,
  T.endereco,
  T.cidade,
  T.bairro,
  T.uf,
  T.cep,
  T.pais,
  T.cnpj,
  T.nome_transp,
  T.cnpj_transp,
  T.qtd_vol_transp,
  T.peso_l_transp,
  T.peso_b_transp,
  T.total_BC,
  T.total_icms,
  T.total_prod,
  T.total_frete,
  T.total_ipi,
  T.total_pis,
  T.total_cofins,
  T.total_trib,
  T.tipo_emissao,
  T.tipo_frete,
  T.tipo_pgto,
  T2.N_Conta_Contabil  
from
  NF_Completa as contabil 
  Full outer join Tabela_CP AS T2 ON T.chave = T2.Chave_Acesso
  fULL OUTER JOIN LANÇAMENTO AS T3 ON T.chave = T3.Chave_Acesso
```

Nesse caso acredito que não seja necessário o `distinct` (embora possa ser utilizado também sem problemas) .

Answer (score -1):

Abaixo apenas uma demonstração de como trazer registro de 3 tabelas. No caso de ter que existir o registro nas 3 tabelas...

```sql
select t1.campo1, t1.campo2, t2.campo1, t3.campo5
from t1, t2, t3
where t2.campo1 = t1.campo1 and t3.campo1 = t2.campo3
```

Para trazer o registro da `tabela1`, mesmo que não contenha na `tabela 2` e `tabela 3`, utilize o `LEFT JOIN`.

Esse [link] pode te ajudar https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Na sua consulta, onde está

```
..., T2.N_Conta_Contabil AS CONTABIL, T3.Nome_Conta_Contabil AS CONTABIL
```

Faça

```
..., COALESCE(T2.N_Conta_Contabil, T3.Nome_Conta_Contabil) AS CONTABIL
```

A função `COALESCE()` retorna o primeiro argumento da esquerda para a direita que é diferente de `NULL`.

Answer (score -2):

Acredito que o que você ta tentando fazer é um CASE na ultima coluna, correto?
ficaria mais ou menos assim:

SELECT DISTINCT
T.id, T.chave, T.natop, T.CFOP, T.nome, T.n_NF, T.data_emissao_NF, T.total_NF, T.endereco, T.cidade, T.bairro, T.uf, T.cep, T.pais, T.cnpj, T.nome_transp, T.cnpj_transp, T.qtd_vol_transp, T.peso_l_transp, T.peso_b_transp, T.total_BC,
T.total_icms, T.total_prod, T.total_frete, T.total_ipi, T.total_pis, T.total_cofins, T.total_trib, T.tipo_emissao, T.tipo_frete, T.tipo_pgto,

**CASE WHEN T2.N_Conta_Contabil IS NULL THEN T3.Nome_Conta_Contabil
ELSE T2.N_Conta_Contabil END
AS CONTABIL**

FROM NF_Completa AS T LEFT OUTER JOIN
Tabela_CP AS T2 ON T.chave = T2.Chave_Acesso FULL OUTER JOIN
LANÇAMENTO AS T3 ON T.chave = T3.Chave_Acesso